# Evenly distribute items on the screen

Tags: algorithm, layout

I am trying to solve this little puzzle (the algorithm): I have N image icons and I want to distribute them evenly on users screen. Say, I put them in a table. If there is one image, there will be one cell in a table. If two - one row with two columns, if three - one row and three columns, if four - two rows, two columns... and so on until row space is gone and since then the table should only grow in columns without adding extra rows.

I'm trying to figure an algorithm for this and perhaps this is something that has a solution already somewhere?

My attempt is so far something like this:

```
obtain_max_rows()
obtain_visible_columns()
if (number_of_pictures > max_rows*max_columns)
{
columns = roundup(number_of_pictures/max_rows)
for(max_rows){generate row;for columns{generate column}}
}
else
{
**here comes to trouble...**
}
```

This logic is bit silly though - it somehow needs to think cases where there are 12 pictures on first screen and 2 on the other trying to balance it say 8/6 or somehow like that.

Comment: *"if three - one row and three columns, if four - two rows"* why? is 3 cols an imposed maximum?

Comment: what happens with five? 1 row and 5 columns. and six with 2 rows and 3 columns

Comment: if it was a prime number, would it just be a single row?

Comment: @chris I don't think that 3 is a maximum. Distributing 4 images is as a 2x2 is more even than a 1x4. I think the pattern is 1 = 1x1, 2 = 1x2, 3 = 1x3, 4 = 2x2, 5 = 1x5, 6 = 2x3, 7 = 1x7 (?), 8 = 2x4, 9 = 3x3 and so on. Only problem is if the numbers are prime (3,7,11) they cant be divided by anything else therefore it has to be a 1xN distribution.

Comment: @ChaseWalden: but why not 3 = 2x2? It is "more even" than 1x3. I guess it depends on what the objective is / how one defines "even". Your pattern looks for "no cell is wasted", i.e. have the number of rows as close as possible to columns, provided that each cell is used. I would have expected the solution to be the smallest square that contains all images. The truth is probably in between ("close to a square, without too much waste"), because your approach would give a single giant line for any prime number.

Comment: @Mathias abolotnov wants to have equally sized cells. 2x2 is 4 cells not 3 therefore there is a wasted space.

Comment: @Mathias I guess he can write a statement that checks if the number of rows is equal 1, it can be arranged differently.

Comment: @ChaseWalden to be clear, your solution is valid. I question the definition of "even", not your solution :) What I mean is, 11 is prime, but I think a 3 x 4 with one cell empty would be more "even" than a 1 x 11 row. Your point about primes is exactly what I have in mind: if you take the question at face value, you are correct, but I suspect a single row is not the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found your answer:

```
    typedef struct{int width, height;} rectangle;

    ...

    rectangle findOptimalDivision(int numberOfCuts){

        int x = numberOfCuts, y = (int)sqrt(numberOfCuts);
        while (x%y) { // when y = 1 it will always exit out (anything can be divided by 1)
            y--;
        }

        return (rectangle){y,numberOfCuts/y};
    }
```

This should give you the height and width of the table (or `rectangle`) in terms of cells.
I tested this with 1 - 100 as the parameter and it seems to give the proper outputs.

Message me if you have any problems.